# Is there a way to make an image stay in proportion?

Tags: html, css, image

Hi I am trying some stuff out with html and css to see what works and what doesn't, and I was wondering if it is possible to make an image stay in the center of your screen and always adapt to the size of the screen. For example an image that  when I look at it on a screen that's 1920*1080 is 192*108 large and when I look at it on a 1600*900 screen it becomes 160*90 whilst the center of the image stays in the middle.

PS: It doesn't matter that the resolution of the image changes even though it makes the image sometimes look terrible.

Comment: Do you also need to maximize the height of the image when it's height is superior to it's width ?

Comment: mind showing some css/html of yours??

Comment: If you have found an answer mark it?

Answer (score 0):

To adapt to the size of the screen,place image in container and then do :

```
   img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto; /*maintains aspect ratio */
   }
```

now image will have the dimension of container!!

To align image in center of your div...do:

```
div{
 width:80%;
 margin:0 auto; /*align div in center first*/
 text-align:center /*center content*/
}
```

Comment: Yes, but he says he want to keep the center of the image in the middle. This will only scale the image.

Comment: That will work only if he needs to optimize the width. But if he also needs to optimize the height (depending on the screen and the image ratio), that's more complicated.

Comment: But isn't it possible to make the div adapt to then size of the screen then? And place it according to the center of the div.

Comment: @user3052776 : mate...without watching your html/css....i can only make wild guesses like m doing in my answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with just an image tag. You could put the image you're using as background-image and then set the sizing to cover. Basically this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('url/to/your/image.jpeg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: though i dint downvote....but ur solution is for backgrounds...not images in div!!

Answer (score 0):

taken from

[Use CSS to make an image scale up and down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821399/use-css-to-make-an-image-scale-up-and-down)

```
img {
    width:100%;
}
```

However, that can easily make the image look like total crap. A safer way might be:

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Either way will get the image changing sizes with browser resizing. However, the second won't stretch the image past its natural size, so it doesn't look deformed.